# Why does saving a Hashtable of non-Parcelable objects in onSaveInstanceState() sometimes work?

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle, parcelable, activity-lifecycle

After going through an introductory Android programming book, I wanted to alter the example application in order to solidify my understanding of some topics that weren't really covered. In making the change, I made an error, but I'm curious why the error worked in some cases but not in others.

An activity within the application stores a series of questions in a `Hashtable<Integer, Question>`, where Question is a small class holding an int and two Strings.  As originally written, the activity downloads the questions from a server on every `onCreate()`, so I wanted to implement `onSaveInstanceState()` to prevent some redundant downloads.  `onSaveInstanceState()` saves the Hashtable into the Bundle using `putSerializable()`.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            // mQuestions is a member variable of 
            // type Hashtable<Integer, Question>
    if (mQuestions != null && mQuestions.size() > 0) {
        outState.putSerializable(SAVED_QUESTIONS, mQuestions);
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly for screen orientation changes even before I knew what a Parcelable was or how to implement one.  I only knew there was a problem when I pressed the emulator's home key and the app silently, invisibly crashed with no LogCat output.  The stack trace led me to look up Parcelable and make Question implement it.

My question isn't what I did wrong.  The question is this: **When the Question class did not implement Parcelable, why did the app crash only on pressing Home and not on a screen orientation change?**

Comment: "onSaveInstanceState() saves the Hashtable into the Bundle using putSerializable()." -- do not put your data model in instance state. Put your data model in a file or a database. That is how you "prevent redundant downloads". " only knew there was a problem when I pressed the emulator's home key and the app silently, invisibly crashed with no LogCat output." -- and your proof of this silent, invisible crash is...what, exactly?

Comment: @CommonsWare: A popup window appeared in Eclipse asking to open the Debug perspective because the launch had suspended.  That's how I knew it crashed.  I've commented out the code to make Question Parcelable, and on one try (out of several), it did force close with errors logged, but that didn't happen before posting this question.

Comment: Yes, the data really should be saved to a file, but that's not what I was trying to do.  I'm not working at a production app (even for personal, hobby use).  I was modifying the demo app created through the _Sam's Teach Yourself Android Application Development in 24 Hours_ book.  Even for an introductory book, it seems to leave out some very basic topics.  I wanted to see how onSaveInstanceState() works.  I think I have the mechanics of it down now, if not when and how best to use it.

Comment: If Eclipse intercepts an exception, you will not see the stack trace in LogCat. Let Eclipse run past the point of the exception, and the stack trace should show up in LogCat.

Comment: I am having a similar problem with serializing a linked list object in onSaveInstanceState(). When I rotate screen orientations, the object is serialized and deserialized with no problems. When I tap the home button, the app crashes in onSaveInstanceState with LogCat reporting a stack overflow error. Anyone have any answer as to why these two situations would yield different results?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand Android doesn't serialize an instance state when recreating an activity after configuration changes. That's why your code works. Persisted objects just don't need to be parcelable because they exist in memory only.

This looks like an optimization. Android knows that the process will not be terminated in this case and there's no need to save the instance state to a file. (In theory the process can be terminated during the configuration change and I don't really know how Android solves this problem).

But when the user presses Home key your app becomes background. And its process can be terminated in case of low memory. Android needs to save activity's state to a file in order to be able to restore your app and its activities in future. In this case the instance state is really serialized and saved to a persistent storage. And that's why your code doesn't work.

Process termination can occur at any moment so you can't rely on some implementation details. Just make instance state parcelable or serializable and you will not face this problem again.

Comment: Although I haven't confirmed it myself, this answer makes sense to me (why serialize something for a configuration change when the variables still persist in memory). It's also the only answer so far that attempts to address the original question as posted by erichamion. Thus I am awarding the bounty to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Quoting Steve Moseley

Note that it is ***NOT*** safe to use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, according to the documentation on Activity states in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.

The document states (in the 'Activity Lifecycle' section):

> Note that it is important to save
>   persistent data in `onPause()` instead
>   of `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`
>   because the later is not part of the
>   lifecycle callbacks, so will not be
>   called in every situation as described
>   in its documentation.

In other words, put your save/restore code in `onPause()` and `onResume()` instead!

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment on the original question, as it is not an answer to the question as posted: "... why did the app crash only on pressing Home and not on a screen orientation change?"

Answer (score 0):

The app did not crash. It was simply shut down when the user clicked the Home key. That's why there was no output to LogCat.

Set a breakpoint in Activity.onDestroy() to confirm this. If I'm right onDestroy() will be called but onSaveInstanceState() will not, because onSaveInstanceState() is only called when the app is placed in the background state, not when it's shut down.

If you need to save the app state upon shutdown, place the code in onDestroy() and save it to something more persistent than a Bundle.

Barry